# cakephp 3.x mail is not working properly in live server

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I am using cakephp 3.x. The email is working properly in localhost but not in case of live server. It is simultaneously giving error like "Transport class "SMTP" not found.".I have been stuck from long time.  Please provide good solution for it.Why it is happening and what should I have to do?  here is my config/app page

```
  'EmailTransport' => [
    'default' => [
        'className' => 'SMTP',
        // The following keys are used in SMTP transports
        'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'port' => 465,
        'timeout' => 30,
        'username' => 'mardshehenshah@gmail.com',
        'password' => '*******',
     //   'client' => null,
     //   'tls' => null,
      //  'url' => env('EMAIL_TRANSPORT_DEFAULT_URL', null),
    ],
],




 'Email' => [
    'default' => [
        'transport' => 'default',
        'from' => 'you@localhost',
        //'charset' => 'utf-8',
        //'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
    ],
],
```

Here is my controller :

```
  $email = new Email('default');
    $email->from(['Abc@gmail.com' => 'Model Broucher Information'])
            ->emailFormat('html')
            ->to($emailAddRess)
            ->subject('About')
            ->send($msg);
```

Comment: I removed the password but consider it still remains in the edits history.

Comment: thanx...I just forgot to remove it. Now  i have changed it .

Comment: Whenever receiving errors, please always post **the _complete_ error**, that is, **including the _full_ stacktrace** (ideally copied from the logs where it is available in a properly readable fashion). Also please try to avoid opening multiple questions for the same problem, instead edit your question and add further information - thanks! That being said, the transport name is `Smtp`, not `SMTP`, case sensitive filesystems require that you match the (file)names properly (`Smtp` finally maps to `SmtpTransport.php`). Also make sure that the file exists and is readable.